# CodeIgniter create a prepared statement or use active record for search with concat

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was wondering how I can prevent SQL injections with this search query of mine? Unfortunately I had to use the string due to me needing to concatenate the first and last names to search. I have tried prepared statements but they don't seem to work here too.

My function

```
public function admin_search($input,$limit,$start){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM agent_accounts as aa LEFT JOIN person as p ON aa.person_id = p.id "
                . "WHERE CONCAT_WS('', p.first_name, p.last_name) LIKE '%$input%' "
                . "OR p.email LIKE '%$input%' OR p.phone_number LIKE '%$input%' "
                . "OR aa.account_number LIKE '%$input%' LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($query->result()as $row){
                $documents[] = $row;
            }
            return $documents;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Codeigniter has its own database class with functions which will prevent SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter Active records automatically escape queries to prevent from SQL injection

Like this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table_name', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

But if you use query siblings

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM agent_accounts as aa LEFT JOIN person as p ON aa.person_id = p.id "
                . "WHERE CONCAT_WS('', p.first_name, p.last_name) LIKE ? "
                . "OR p.email LIKE ? OR p.phone_number LIKE ? "
                . "OR aa.account_number LIKE ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql,array('%{$input}%','%{$input}%','%{$input}%','%{$input}%',$limit,$start));
```

The question marks in the query are automatically replaced with the values from array.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping! However when I try to search for something like john smith which is the first and last name concatenated, nothing appears for some reason.

Comment: print your query using `echo $this->db->last_query()`  and execute in DB. Debug query Whats wrong with it.@JianYA

Comment: SELECT * FROM agent_accounts as aa LEFT JOIN person as p ON aa.person_id = p.id WHERE CONCAT_WS('', p.first_name, p.last_name) LIKE '%{$input}%' OR p.email LIKE '%{$input}%' OR phone_number LIKE '%{$input}%' OR aa.account_number LIKE '%{$input}%' LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0

Comment: That is the query that is run. I'm not sure if thats correct